# Change Combobox via Textbox Input VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, binding, combobox, textbox

Hi I need some help over here... how do i change the display member of a ComboBox after i have entered a code in a textbox that it represent the combobox value??

example

Code: 02-001        Combobox: Provider X

if i change the code the provider combobox must change and if i change the provider combobox the code should change!.. i haven't found any help.. heres little code I remember

```
if e.keychar = chr(13) Then
    combobox.valuemember = textbox.text
    combobox.displaymember = me.stockdataset.selectprovider(@textbox.text)
end if
```

this code change the combo box display member but if I change the comobox by clicking it the code on the textbox doesnt change, to its corresponding code...??
please help

....the combo box is bound to the provider tables....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong binding way....This is how you do it:
I have simulate your case by a simple form with a combobox and a textbox
and a datatable with 2 columns "Code" and "Description"

and here the Code (if you please, dont forget to mark my answer as **Right**):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try

            Me.KeyPreview = True'To Enable the Key events : KeyDown, KeyPress and KeyUp

            Dim dt As New DataTable("T")
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Code"))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Description"))
            For i = 1 To 10
                Dim r As DataRow = dt.NewRow
                r("Code") = "Code" + CStr(i)
                r("Description") = "Desc" + CStr(i)
                dt.Rows.Add(r)
            Next

            With ComboBox1
                .ValueMember = "Code" ' This is case sensitive 
                .DisplayMember = "Description" ' This is case sensitive 
                .DataSource = dt
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
        SetComoboValue()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then SetComoboValue()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetComoboValue()
        Try
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
                ComboBox1.SelectedValue = TextBox1.Text
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Ooops, Invalid code !!!")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

**So** when you enter **"Code3"** and hit Enter or Click the TextBox1, the ComboBox1 will display **"Desc3"**

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooo thanks that really really help a lot just one question why does my combobox seems to disorder the providers? is it normal? thats the only thing thanx for the answer

Comment: I dont know what query(or some thing else) in your providers Datatable, lets say its "select Code, Description From providers" to make it sort just make it "select Code, Description From providers ORDER BY Description"

Comment: well I'm binding directly from the provider table into the combobox not sure if that is why it seems to be disorder, but well that doesn't matter right now :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the selectedItem of your combobox when user press enter. But before, check that it is indeed in the provider list...

in the SelectionChanged handler of your combobox, set the textbox content to the value of the combobox.

Better each time use properties that uses propertychanged, and bind textbox and combobox's selectedItem to those properties.

Comment: so the SelectedItems are the values of binding controls